# Post form data with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, cheerio

How can i post input form data as a url. The sample code shown below.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/scrape', function(req, res){
    const name = req.body.username;
    res.send('You sent the name "' + name + '".');    
});

app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {
    const name = req.body.username;
    res.send('You sent the name "' + name + '".');    

    url = `http://www.github.com/${name}`;

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        // 
        //
        //
        })
        res.send('Check your console!')
    })
})
```

So I want get username on index page and post form value to the scrape.

Comment: FYI, you can't have two `res.send()` statements for the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make a get or a post request?
If you are trying to make a get request it should work this way

```
request("http://www.github.com/whatever", function (error, response,html) {
console.log(response)
})
```

For form-data read more https://github.com/request/request#forms

```
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, 
function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
```

});

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, actually I want to use 'name' data which prompted index page and use it like this way; http://github.com/{name}